# No neutral at electric meter

Tags: electrical, wiring, neutral, meter

I'm runing power to a barn. I'm getting the power from my electric meter that powers the whole property. I ran conduit underground from meter pole to to a breaker box I installed in the barn. I ran 3 wires inside the conduit 2 hot & one neutral. At the meter pole I installed a 100 amp shut off switch. At this switch I connected both hots & the neutral. I am connecting 3 wires from this box to the electric meter but, when I removed the meter the only wires there are 2 black hot wires & a bare copper ground wire. I'm confused as to where or why there is no neutral & what I do with the neutral wire from the shut off box.

Comment: Are you sure the copper wire isn’t the neutral? Anyway take a pic of your meter socket and main panel with the cover off (CAREFULLY) and post it here.

Comment: Who do you have for an electric utility?

Comment: You're connecting directly to the meter base without having the utility power shut off? That's bold.

Comment: How about a photo of the connections to the meter base. What size is the bare wire at this point the neutral and ground are the same thinh and if the neutral is ~~ 70 of the of size hot conductors the ground minimum is #6 for rod& plate electrodes ufer grounds #4 max, so what’s up a big uninsulated ground at the utility is quite common